# Timestamp not in ISO8601 format. Amazon MWS and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm trying to make a simple SubmitFeed, but I'm getting an error that says "Timestamp must be in ISO8601 format". This is what I have:

```
def make_update_feed(host, seller_id, mws_auth_token, aws_access_key_id, secret_key, xml):
       date_now = dt.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "Z"
       xml_md5_b64 = md5_b64_hash(xml)
       timestamp = urllib.quote_plus(date_now) 
       params = "AWSAccessKeyId={0}&Action=SubmitFeed&ContentMD5Value={1}&FeedType=_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_&MWSAuthToken={2}&Merchant={3}&PurgeAndReplace=false&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp={4}&Version=2009-01-01".format(aws_access_key_id,urllib.quote_plus(xml_md5_b64),mws_auth_token,seller_id,timestamp)
       string_2_sign = "POST\n{0}\n/\n{1}".format(host,params)
       signature = hmac_sha256_b64(string_2_sign, secret_key)
       params_req = {
            "AWSAccessKeyId": urllib.quote_plus(aws_access_key_id),
            "Action": "SubmitFeed",
            "ContentMD5Value": urllib.quote_plus(xml_md5_b64),
            "FeedType": "_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_",
            "MWSAuthToken": urllib.quote_plus(mws_auth_token),
            "Merchant": urllib.quote_plus(seller_id),
            "PurgeAndReplace": False,
            "SignatureMethod": "HmacSHA256",
            "SignatureVersion": 2,
            "Timestamp":  timestamp,
            "Version": "2009-01-01",
            "Signature": urllib.quote_plus(signature),
            }

       headers = {
            'Host': urllib.quote_plus(host),
            'Content-Type': "text/xml",
            "x-amazon-user-agent": "MyPythonApp/1.0 (Language=Python)"
            }

       data_xml = {
            'FeedContent': xml
           }
       url = "https://%s" % host
       r = requests.post(url, params=params_req, headers=headers,data=data_xml)
       return r
```

Now, when I run my function with the respective parameters, I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Timestamp 2018-02-19T14%3A30%3A50Z must be in ISO8601 format</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestID>7c8631e4-8d61-4f46-9256-af0130028d96</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

However, I can see that the timestamp is in ISO8601 format. I don't know why it's giving me that error. Also, both the xml hash and the signature are correct (I checked vs Amazon Scratchpad, and they were the same). Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try to not urlencode your timestamp content? Maybe it chokes on the %3A's.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion, but it gives me another error: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided". I checked vs the scratchpad, and I have the same signature.

Comment: And how was  all solved?
I catch the same shit

Comment: I have the same issue too :( Did you solved it?